# Write a palindrome that prints "Hello, World!" without using comments

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, palindrome

Your Task: Print "Hello, World!" using a palindrome.

Simple, right?

Nope.

## You have one restriction: **you may not use comments.**

"Comments" include

- Normal `//` or `#` comments
- Adding extraneous characters to a string literal
- Triple-quoted string comments
- Creating a string literal to hide characters

You may not use a pre-defined procedure to print "Hello, World!". (like HQ9+'s H command)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Almost duplicate.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/59527/8478) I'll leave it up to the community to decide whether the comment restriction makes a sufficient difference or not. (Although I personally don't think comment restrictions work... once you get to 2D languages, you can easily include all sorts of code that isn't a no-op, but never happens to be executed.)

Comment: This challenge has been done so much, it's been solved as 1 or even 0 byte answers in multiple languages

Comment: I'm voting to close as a duplicate, since there are *many* answers from the other challenge that can be used without modification here.

Comment: Maybe you can make it harder by requiring all the code affecting the output. Otherwise you get answers containing like-comments and one doesn't feel worth to write a more sophisticated one.

Comment: @CrazyPython Updating rules after an answer has been posted is highly frowned upon, on top of this already being a duplicate. For future challenges, I highly recommend using [The Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/42963) so you can get meaningful feedback on challenges before they're posted.

Comment: @TimmyD In this case it is necessary to close loopholes. It also only invalidates joke answers.

Comment: The center of the challenge is no comments. That makes it 300% harder. It's [tag:restricted-source].

Comment: @CrazyPython The fact that "joke" answers were allowed under the rules-as-originally-written highlights the fact that this challenge wasn't ready for posting to main. The fact that you're adding "no comments" to the restrictions *doesn't* change the fact that many answers from the linked challenge can be posted here without modification, making this one a duplicate.

Comment: @TimmyD The original question the no comment restriction, I simply made it in a larger font.

Comment: @CrazyPython No, sorry for being unclear. I meant that adding "no comments" as a restriction to "palindrome Hello World" doesn't make it a sufficiently different enough challenge to not be a duplicate. If you want to discuss this further, let's take it to chat.

Answer (score 4):

### Stuck, 0 bytes

I think this wins? An empty program in stuck prints `Hello, World!`

Shamelessly stolen from [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55425/32686)

Comment: And we have a winner.. +1

Comment: I just posted this to show how bad/repeated this challenge was, I don't expect anything from it

Comment: Standard loophole guidelines?

Comment: Look at the new rules.

Answer (score 2):

## Bash, 47 bytes

```
echo Hello, World!
exit
tixe
!dlroW, olleH ohce
```

Answer (score 1):

## Gogh, 31 bytes

```
"Hello, World!"Ƥ"!dlroW ,olleH"
```

---

#### Explanation

```
"Hello, World!"    “ Push the string literal ”
¡                  “ Output the TOS          ”
"!dlroW ,olleH"    “ Push the string literal ”
                   “ Non-implicit output     ”
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Help, WarDoq!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Help,_WarDoq!), 1 byte

```
H
```

Print Hello, World!.

Comment: And now with 2 bytes?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find a 2 byte palindrome for hello world :(